# Hubspot integration with React.js

Tags: reactjs, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api, hubspot-cms

I am looking out for resources through which I can integrate hubspot in my React based web Application . I will really appreciate if someone can take out some time and help me with it's resources , Thanks !

I tried looking for it on youtube but I want a professional or experienced advice since I'll be integrating it in a live app , I don't want to mess up with code following a tutorial from youtube .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, stackoverflow is not the place to ask for someones resources but since I am currently working on basically the same, I decided to give you a short advice on this.

So the firtst thing i would start with is to read a bit into the official documentation of HubSpot rather then following a youtube tutorial which can be outdated. here is a helpful link where you can start: [Hubspot Developers - ReactJS](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/guides/js-frameworks#reactjs)

HubSpot offers very detailed documentation about their API & Framework integrations so you can do a lot with that.

If you think it's too risky putting your code directly in a production app, try to create a blank app and play around with the integration until you get an idea of how things are working on their side.

in my opinion, there is not much you can do wrong or mess up. as long as you are familiar with how React works and know the basics of Hubspot, it will work out.